# How do you use imagemap control in asp.net with masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagemap

I have got a masterpage with a picture on it, I attached the image map control with the picture.. but when i navigate to a child page.. the picture is not triggered. Is there a way to put an image map control on the masterpage and activate it through the child page?

```
<asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/header.png" 
                                  HotSpotMode="Navigate" onclick="ImageMap1_Click" Target="~/AllQuestions.aspx">
                                  <asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom="1000" HotSpotMode="Navigate" Left="1000" 
                                      NavigateUrl="~/AllQuestions.aspx" Right="500" Top="500" />
                              </asp:ImageMap>
```

It isnt clickable in the child page

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the hot spots correctly? set the redius of circle big enough so that user will be able to find it. compare your code with following code check if all the values are set properly:

```
<asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" HotSpotMode="Navigate" 
     ImageUrl="~/CarImages/mitsubishicedia.jpg" onclick="ImageMap1_Click">
  <asp:CircleHotSpot HotSpotMode="Navigate" NavigateUrl="~/FeedbackPage.aspx" 
    Radius="50" />
</asp:ImageMap>
```

Comment: is it working now? if not then try putting smaller values for bottom, top, right or left because these variables sets co-ordinates for rectangle eg. left sets x-ordinate for left edge of rectangle, and right sets y-ordinate for left edge of rectangle, and top sets y-ordinate for top edge and vice versa.

Comment: And most Importantly keep top!=bottom and right!=left. let me know if its still not working. hope it helps!